# Sending Client Data With a Timer

Tags: python, server, client, client-server

So I have a simple Client-Server.

They properly connect with command line arguments, send and receiving data.

When the server isn't up and running but the client executes: Attempt to connect, after 1 second display message that it timed out (3 times) before closing.

the closest i can come to it, is simply attempting it 3 times.

```
import sys
from socket import *
# Get the server hostname, port and data length as command line arguments
argv = sys.argv
host = argv[1]
port = argv[2]
count = argv[3]

# Command line argument is a string, change the port and count into integer
port = int(port)
count = int(count)
data = 'X' * count # Initialize data to be sent

# Create UDP client socket. Note the use of SOCK_DGRAM
clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

# Sending data to server
# times out after 1 second (?)
for i in range(3):
        try:
            print("Sending data to " + host + ", " + str(port) + ": " + data)
            clientsocket.sendto(data.encode(),(host, port)) 
            # Receive the server response
            dataEcho, address = clientsocket.recvfrom(count)
            # Display the server response as an output
            print("Receive data from " + address[0] + ", " + str(address[1]) + ": " + dataEcho.decode())
            break
        except:
            print("timed out")
        finally:
            #Close the client socket
            clientsocket.close()
```

How would I add a timer to it? Just adding 1 second between each attempt instead of how I coded.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the program to sleep for x seconds you could `import time`, and then add `time.sleep(num_of_seconds_to_sleep)` after your `clientsocket.close()` line.

Comment: So, I understand that... but would it be the same thing as "Attempt to connect for 1 second, time out after", I feel as though those are two different things, or i may just be overthinking it

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the issue. I see your program attempts to connect to the server, but if it doesn't it tries two more times. What I interpret you asking for is a way to wait x seconds between attempts for some reason (maybe give the server more time to init). Is this correct?